# Predict frequencies in a Normal (Gaussian) distribution - sum of squared residuals

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, standard-deviation

I'm studying a course (Mathematics for Machine Learning). There's a quiz that is designed to test knowledge on using a model to fit data to predict frequencies in a Normal (Gaussian) distribution. The model used basically uses two parameters (Mean (**μ**) and Standard deviation (**σ**)), which are tweaked to enable the model to fit the data (in the right bell curve shape) for optimised prediction. The two parameters can be in a vector **p**. The question is as follows:

--------------------- START OF QUESTION ---------------------

Since each parameter vector **p** represents a different bell curve, each with its own value for the sum of squared residuals, **SSR**, we can draw the surface of **SSR** values over the space spanned by **p**, such as **μ** and **σ** in this example.

Here is an illustration of this surface for our data.

[image]

Every point on this surface represents the SSR of a choice of parameters, with some bell curves performing better at representing the data than others.

We can take a ‘top-down’ view of the surface, and view it as a contour map, where each of the contours (in green here) represent a constant value for the **SSR**.

[image]

The goal in machine learning is to find the parameter set where the model fits the data as well as it possibly can. This translates into finding the lowest point, the global minimum, in this space.

--------------------- END OF QUESTION ---------------------

The question then provides some statements, where I have to choose true or false. But before that, I don't even understand certain things about the question itself.

1- I didn't understand what is causing the effect of the contours, and why is it in the shape of a contour and not any other shape?

2- I didn't understand the graph itself. Why are the two parameters: Mean (**μ**) and Standard deviation (**σ**) had ***cm*** as units of measurements, while SSR is in decimals going up in intervals: 0.01, 0.02 ...etc.

3- Is this the right interpretation to say: that if we get to the center of the hole in the surface, this means we have reached the global minima - the most optimised parameters, causing the model to predict correctly?

4- If my statement in the previous question is correct, then referring to the second diagram, is it correct to say then, that a Standard deviation of 8cm and a Mean of 178cm gives us the global minima? Or am I incorrectly  interpreting the graph?

5- There's another question that follows, which is of similar nature, but again I didn't understand how to interpret the graph. The question is as follows:

--------------------- START OF QUESTION ---------------------

Often we can't see the whole parameter space, so instead of just picking the lowest point, we have to make educated guesses where better points will be.

We can define another vector, **Δp**, in the same space as **p** that tells us what change can be made to **p** to get a better fit.

For example, a model with parameters **p'** = **p** + **Δp** will produce a better fit to data, if we can find a suitable **Δp**.

The second course in this specialisation will detail how to calculate these changes in parameters, **Δp**.

Given the following contour map,

[image]

What **Δp** will give the best improvement in the model?

[image]

--------------------- END OF QUESTION ---------------------

I didn't understand how to read the graph. Why is **Δp** = [-2,2]?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: No answer... but that question with a multiple choice rubric just seems weird...

Comment: Hi David. The questions are from the Coursera course - Mathematics for Machine Learning. If you don't have an answer and find the questions weird, and you have a reputation of 11.2K in Mathematics, then what hope do I have? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am taking this course. I accidentally saw your question while searching for the answers =))) because I failed the first attempt. Idk if you solve this one or not, I just want to have a little discussion.
On the second try, I answered right those 2 questions. Here are my answers to some of your questions:

2 - Mean (μ) and Standard deviation (σ) had cm as units of measurement because they are measuring the height in cm, this question is the continuation of the previous questions. So in question 5, they gave us the formula to calculate SSR, which is always equal to or greater than 0. If your question is more about why the interval is 0.01, I don't have the answer either.

3 - Yes, I think you are right.

4 - Yes, I think you are right. Standard deviation of 8cm and a Mean of 178cm gives us the global minima BUT that combination is based on looking at the graph. If we use calculation, ..., maybe we can find a better combination. You can use the code block in question 5 to calculate the SSR (it would be 0.0005087223...). Actually, 178 and 8 was my answer for question 5 :D

5 - We have p' = p + Δp. When Δp = [-2,2], by visualization, we see our p' will be closer to the center of the hole than p. So SSR will be smaller. Also, Δp = [-2,2] means we should decrease the mean by 2cm, and increase the sd by 2cm. You can use the code block in question 5 to stimulate this one too.
I don't major in mathematics, so my explanation is simple and maybe it only makes sense to me. But I still hope it helps you!